# convert sql table to xml name value pair

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I need to convert an sql table data  which has fieldname as **actionname,actiondesc**  I need to convert that in to below format

```
   <Details>
   <Field name="actiondesc" value="val1"/>
    <Field name="actionname" value="val2"/>
     </Details>
```

Thanks in advance
Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97f70/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```sql
create table dbo.YourTable
(
  actiondesc int,
  actionname int
);

insert into dbo.YourTable values(1,2);
insert into dbo.YourTable values(3,4);
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
select 'actiondesc' as [Field/@name],
       T.actiondesc as [Field/@value],
       '',
       'actionname' as [Field/@name],
       T.actionname as [Field/@value]
from dbo.YourTable as T
for xml path('Details')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97f70/1/0)**:

```xml
<Details>
  <Field name="actiondesc" value="1" />
  <Field name="actionname" value="2" />
</Details>
<Details>
  <Field name="actiondesc" value="3" />
  <Field name="actionname" value="4" />
</Details>
```